# hHw to loop a number to fill a list alternately

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I have codes shown below, I am trying to print a number to fill the list. The value of i here will index to another list. how to loop so that the value of i in the list "(urls[i])" will always change from zero until it reach the value of length.

I have try this but its only print number from 1-8 (which is the length of list named urls)

```
length=len(urls) //this is my input, the value of urls will 
            // depend on the result of my previeous code
i=0
while i<length:
  print(i)
  i += 1
result2 = requests.get(urls[i]) ///i want the value of i here  
        // to be increased by 1 everytime its looping
src2 = result2.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')
links2 = soup.find_all('p')
print(links2)
```

Comment: You assigned something to `length` but never used it; you use `num` but never assign anything to it.  This means that the posted code will fail when it tries to use `num`.

Comment: Can you provide a better example for what you have an what you want? (input and output). It is hard to understand your question based on the wording and the example provided. Cheers.

Comment: `while i<length:`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to indent your code:

```
while i<length:
  print(i)
  i += 1
  //i want the value of i here to be increased by 1 everytime its looping
  result2 = requests.get(urls[i])
  src2 = result2.content
  soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')
  links2 = soup.find_all('p')
  print(links2)
```